# Prove that a set is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A\subseteq \Bbb R$, A is an infinite set of positive numbers.

Suppose, $\exists k \in 
\Bbb Z$ for all finite $B\subseteq A$.

$\sum_{b\in B}b<k$

Prove $A$ is countable.

I have a hint: $A_n=\lbrace a \in A | a>\frac1n\rbrace$

I understand that $B \in \Bbb Q$ and $k$ can be the last element of $A$ but I'm not really sure if that's right or what to do with it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is $k$? Is $Z=\Bbb Z$?

Comment: Do you mean $\exists k\in\Bbb Z$ *such that for all finite* $B$...?

Comment: For an infinite set, it makes no sense to say "the last element".

Comment: Git, yes I couldn't find the right command for it, I edited it now.
Stefan yes.
GEdgar, I see.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Prove that each $A_n$ must be finite, and hence that $A=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}A_n$ is countable. If $A_n$ is infinite, and all of its elements are bigger than $\frac1n$, then there is a finite $B\subseteq A_n$ such that ... ?

Comment: Brian, I know that it takes less time to write an answer than to find a duplicate. But you must remember that you answered this exact same question not one week ago. EDIT: In fact, two days ago.

Comment: @Asaf: I did remember, and I checked before I wrote: it is **not** an exact duplicate.

Comment: Take a look at the two questions, side by side. It's the same question, with only one very minor difference. $\leq k$ and $<k$ on the summation. Big whoop... :-)

Comment: @Asaf: Look again. This one talks about sums over finite subsets; the other one about sums over countable subsets. The **solution** is essentially the same, but for many of those just encountering these ideas the **problems** are not.

Comment: The difference seems to be the finiteness assumption on $B$ in this version. I don't know if that is a big enough difference. Anyhow, I already voted to close before noticing that.

Comment: Ah, this one only asks about finite subsets. Seeing how the notation is downright the same, and the hint is the same; and that your answer is essentially the same (as the problem is essentially the same)... I still feel that this is a duplicate "enough" to merit a closure.

Comment: @Harald: Yes, that’s exactly the difference. And to a lot of beginners it’s a significant difference, which is why I went to the trouble of typing up an answer instead of voting to close as a duplicate.

Comment: If the other question talks about countable subsets and this one about finite one, then the solution for the other question applies to this question, too. Would it then be acceptable to vote this one as duplicate of the other? Because it is in a sense a "proper subset" of the other one.

Comment: @Asaf: Having taught more than my share of weak students over the years, I prefer to err on the side of helpfulness.

Comment: @Stefan: If you’ve read the comments, you know that I don’t think that it’s a good idea, and why.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I'm actually asking this to myself. I still haven't found a reasonable answer to this, seeing the pros and the contras. Anyway, I voted to close before seeing the difference, I'm going to retract my vote because it was based on false assumptions.

Comment: "a "proper subset" of the other one." That was pretty funny actually. I checked my paper again and it should be $\le$, it is the same question, though it seems we understood it differently. I still don't get it even after going through the other post. $A$ is just one set. Is it even possible to "break" $A$ into many subsets ?

Comment: @GinKin: What you actually have is $A_1\subseteq A_2\subseteq A_3\subseteq\ldots$, and $$A=\bigcup_{n\ge 1}A_n\;.$$ If $a\in A$, then $a>0$, so $a>\frac1n$ for some $n$, and therefore $a\in A_n$.

Comment: @GinKin: If it's the same question, why did you limit yourself to finite subsets, and Oria posted the question with "any subset"?

Comment: I don't know, I don't think I even understood the question properly. As to why Oria thought the way he did, I can't possibly know.